# Why spinning creates bulges?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, rotational-dynamics, planets, centrifugal-force

Earth isnt a perfect but has bulges because of its spinning. What actually creates the bulges? Is the same reason that makes a liquid have v shape in a rotational tube?

Comment: You might find this useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force

Comment: Also this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force

Comment: And this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_motion